# sum() on multiple columns with group by function

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by, sum

I need to gather the count from each column and there are multiple results for each row. the problem is that the columns are duplicating the value of the first column.

```
  $sql="SELECT MODEL, 
     sum(CLICK) AS LOCCLICK, sum(VIEW) AS LOCVIEW, sum(EMAIL) AS LOCEMAIL, sum(SHARE) AS LOCSHARE
      FROM     STAT
      WHERE    ID = ".$id."
      GROUP BY MODEL";
       $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $clickcoun = $row['LOCCLICK'];
                $viewcoun = $row['LOCVIEW'];
                $emailcoun = $row['LOCEMAIL'];
                $sharecoun = $row['LOCSHARE'];
                $model = $row['MODEL'];
                echo "\n";
                // Log the stats into the daily updates.
                 $sqlx = 'INSERT INTO DAILY (ID, QDATE, VIEWS, CLICKS, EMAILS, SHARES, MODEL) 
                VALUES ('.$id.', NOW(), '.$viewcoun.', '.$clickcoun.', '.$emailcoun.', '.$sharecoun.', "'.$model.'" )';
                  $mysqli->query($sqlx);
                  } 
                 } else {
                      echo "0 results"; die();
                 }
```

The result I am looking for are as follows:

Ford: views = 302, emails = 21, shares = 10

Dodge: views = 567, emails = 41, shares = 13

Chevrolet: views = 324, emails = 23, shares = 9

I want to enter these into a daily stats breakdown so I can query them throw them into a graph and display their daily reach. at the end of the month i plan to break these down again the same way for a monthly overview.

Comment: I don't understand the problem statement. Could you please share some sample data and the result you're trying to achieve so it would be clearer?

Comment: Can yu give 4 rows of example data n explain what exactly yu want..?

Comment: What do you mean by *"duplicating the value of the first column."*? I think you are mixing rows and columns in your problem description.

Comment: I made the changes you requested to be more clear. GolezTrol I know the difference I need the count for each column because the rows have inserted data from other traffic sources that have numbers such as 21 for the emails along with the stats provided by the initial site that I am gathering stats for.

Comment: What is the value of your columns email, click and views

Comment: they are int values and they are numbers like 23 or 1009 or 5 etc.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop to do this.  Just use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO DAILY (ID, MODEL, CLICKS, VIEWS, EMAIL, SHARES, QDATE) 
    SELECT $id, MODEL, sum(CLICK) AS LOCCLICK, sum(VIEW) AS LOCVIEW,
           sum(EMAIL) AS LOCEMAIL, sum(SHARE) AS LOCSHARE, now()
    FROM STAT
    WHERE ID = ".$id."
    GROUP BY MODEL;
```

Comment: I am trying this and it's not working, I am kinda confused on how the now() works along with the select. maybe that's where it's not working?